# iOS retrieving voice mail Number through api

Tags: iphone, voicemail

Is it possible to retrieve voice mail number saved in the iPhone. if possible please let me know the way to retrieve it.

Comment: please can you give me the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the phone number of the phone.